# How to count DbSet rows added to in a DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-core

Looked high and low but cannot find the syntax to count the number of rows in a [DbContext].[DbSet Entity] by the change status of the row. Specifically, I would like to know how many rows in one entity/table were added and are pending SaveChanges().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries` method overloads (similar to [EF6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)):

```
var addedCount = db.ChangeTracker.Entries<YourEntity>()
    .Count(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm having trouble finding comprehensive documentation for EF Core and there are warnings that it has important distinctions from EF6, so I'm hesitant to reference EF6 documentation.

Comment: Yeah, there is absolutely no class documentation, so all we have is the Intellisense :( And here is one of the few places where I could include a lnk to EF6 documentation since (at least currently) this particular part is the same.

Answer (score 1):

(First answer, so be gentle)
I had a similar problem. One approach is to override the context SaveChanges method as proposed here: https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/

But in your situation a special method on your context class might be more appropriate:

```
public virtual Tuple<int, int> CountChanges()
{
    var modified = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).Count();
    var added = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).Count();
    return new Tuple<int, int>(modified, added);
}
```